# Using cookie with request

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to send cookie with URL for request. But I am getting no output. The code:

```
header ={('cookies','ecrZipInput=55401')}
response = requests.get('www.url.com', cookie=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way instead :

```
response = requests.get('www.url.com', cookies={'ecrZipInput':'55401'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

Notice that the parameter name is *plural* 'cookies' and it accepts dictionary value.

[See : [`Requests` Quickstart > Cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies)]